# How to get rid of empty tooltips while displaying error messages on tooltips in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip, jsf-2.2

I display error messages somewhere on `<p:tooltip>` as follows.

```
<p:inputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}" required="true"/>

<p:tooltip for="text">
    <p:message for="text"/>
</p:tooltip>
```

Although it displays an error message the given tooltip, an empty/unnecessary tooltip is shown, when there  is no error as can be seen in the following picture - beside the bottom right corner of the text box.

[image]

How to get rid of such empty tooltips? (I tried someway but it did not work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by checking for an error message in the list `java.util.List<FacesMessage>` that can be obtained by using `facesContext.messageList`.

The `rendered` attribute of `<p:tooltip>` can be set based on the error message/s found in the list for the associated component/s something along the line.

```
rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('clientId')}"
```

A working code snippet :

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panel id="panel">
        <p:inputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}" required="true"/>

        <p:tooltip for="text" rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('form:text')}">
            <p:message for="text"/>
        </p:tooltip>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="panel"/>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

---

Or by using component binding. Such as,

```
<p:inputText id="text" binding="#{inputComponent}" value="#{bean.text}"/>

<p:tooltip for="text" rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(inputComponent.clientId)}">
    <p:message for="text"/>
</p:tooltip>
```

Or even

```
<p:inputText id="text" binding="#{inputComponent}" value="#{bean.text}"/>

<p:tooltip for="text" rendered="#{not inputComponent.valid}">
    <p:message for="text"/>
</p:tooltip>
```

The last two cases are useful especially when the (input) component is enclosed within an iterating component like a `<p/h:dataTable>`, `<p:dataGrid>`, `<p:dataList>` (or even `<ui:repeat>`) where the uniqueness of enclosing components is determined based on the iterating row index of an iterating component such as, `form:dataTable:0:text`, `form:dataTable:1:text`, `form:dataTable:2:text`... and so on

Answer (score 0):

p:tooltip should have a "rendered" attribute, set it to false

from documentation:

> rendered : default=TRUE - value to specify the rendering of the 
>   component, when set to false component will not be  rendered.

Source: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/p-tooltip.pdf

Comment: OK but based on what condition the `rendered` attribute is to be set so that it does not display an empty tooltip? The tooltip should only be shown, if there is an error.

Comment: you can get the "component" using jsf (findComponent) and call the *valid* method in it. Something like: <p:tooltip for="text" rendered="#{! textComponent.valid}">

Comment: try <p:tooltip for="text" rendered="#{testManagedBean.text != ""}"> be sure to change quotes to single inside the EL expression. Make sure you update the component too if necessary.