# Conditionally render depending on presence of a faces message

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message, jsf-2.2, conditional-rendering

I have a special row in my table for errors:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p:message for="questionId" id="msgQuestion" /></td>
</tr>
```

How can I set this so the row is only displayed when there is an error?

Comment: Is this a plain HTML table, hereby, it is neither a standard JSF component  (like `<h:dataTable>`) nor a PrimeFaces component (like `<p:dataTable>`)?

Comment: If rows inside the table are static (thus, `<tr>` is not wrapped inside `<c:forEach>` and/or `<ui:repeat>` iterating components), then the same can be achieved using a component like `<p:panelGrid>` and conditionally rendering `<p:row rendered="#{someCriteria}" ...>` inside it.

Comment: I could use a panelGroup around the tr tag but I don't know what condition to render it.

Comment: i.e. how can I tell whether the p:message is displaying an error or not?

Comment: I have ever done something similar as stated by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25187426/1391249).

Answer (score 0):

In first place i will recommend [not to use table to display layout elements](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)

after that the  ellement will apear even if the message is not present, if you are obliged to use it you can use som think like this in JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
  hideTdMessage();
};
hideTdMessage(){
var message = document.getElementById(msgQuestion);
if(message){
   //the msg is present
}else{
   //the msg is not present 
}}
</script>
```

Or You can use your MBean to change the CSS class it's better than using JS.

But i will say that the best solution is not tu use the tabel.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSF component and the property rendered

```
rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}"
```